# Fit Data to Reciprocal Function with Exponent

Tags: python, scipy, data-fitting

I want to fit a set of XY data points to a reciprocal exponential function in Python 3.8. I'm attempting to use the `leastsq` function of the `scipy.optimize` library.

I wish to fit my data to a function akin to the following:

[image]

Where `d`, `s`, and `e` are all the function parameters I wish to fit to my data.

I have some example data which I'd like to fit the function above to, and the following testing script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    # Declare example data
    dataX = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17]
    dataY = [0.00000000e+00,  2.47076895e-03,  9.66638150e-03,  1.97670203e-02, 3.42218835e-02,  4.97943540e-02,  6.54004261e-02,  7.93484613e-02, 8.61083796e-02,  8.49273950e-02,  6.70327841e-02,  3.45946900e-02, -2.24559129e-02, -1.17023372e-01, -2.49244700e-01, -4.27837601e-01, -6.61529080e-01, -9.62240010e-01, -1.35215046e+00, -1.84177480e+00, -2.46428273e+00, -3.25198094e+00, -4.24238794e+00, -5.53021367e+00, -7.23278230e+00, -9.57603920e+00, -1.31432215e+01, -1.99465466e+01, -1.45862198e+01, -1.01563667e+01, -7.19977087e+00, -5.03349403e+00, -3.37202972e+00, -2.07966002e+00]

    # Fit to reciprocal exponential function
    guessDenom = 1
    guessPow = 2
    guessShift = -10

    optimalFx = lambda args: -(args[0] / pow(dataX + args[2], args[1])) - dataY
    finalDenom, finalPow, finalShift = leastsq(optimalFx, [guessDenom, guessPow, guessShift])[0]

    dataYFitted = []

    for x in dataX:
        dataYFitted.append(-finalDenom / pow(x + finalShift, finalPow))

    # Plot original & fitted data
    plt.xlim([0, 17])
    plt.ylim([-30, 30])
    plt.plot(dataX, dataYFitted, label = "Fitted Function", color = "dodgerblue")
    plt.plot(dataX, dataY, label = "Original Data", color = "gray", alpha = 0.5)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
    plt.clf()

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

The script above takes the example data, and attempts to fit the function above using a lambda expression. It also graphs the original data along the fitted function at the discrete X intervals. I've used this approach before for other functions and it worked as intended, however with this reciprocal exponential function it doesn't appear to work properly.

Firstly, upon running the script above, I get the following warnings:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
optimalFx = lambda args: -(args[0] / pow(dataX + args[2], args[1])) - dataY

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
optimalFx = lambda args: -(args[0] / pow(dataX + args[2], args[1])) - dataY

RuntimeWarning: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800.
warnings.warn(errors[info][0], RuntimeWarning)
```

And the following final plot is generated:
[image]

Since the supposed fitted function is not even visible, something is clearly going wrong.

What I'm assuming is happening here is the fact that, at a certain point in the library trying to find a good fit, it encounters a division by 0 and it fails. This can be evident if one simply plots the reciprocal exponential function:

[image]

At a certain point an answer of `ind` must be getting encountered.

How does one fit the reciprocal exponential function to a data set with the `scipy.optimize` library in Python without running into this issue?
Is there perhaps a way to restrict the checking domains for each argument provided to the `leastsq` function?

Comment: At around x=14, is that where the true function would go to negative infinity?

Comment: For this specific sample data yes, however I'd want to also use this fitting on other simillar data.

Comment: When it comes to fitting data, I think it works best when the function is continuous over the range of interest.

Comment: Right, so there is no way to use the `leastsq` function to fit to a function that is not entirely continuous? Is there perhaps a way to restrict the checking domains for each argument provided to the `leastsq` function?

Comment: Do you have solid reasons to use such a nasty function with a singularity ? My first reaction is: there is something wrong in trying to fit that, not in the fitting algorithm. Do you have an underlying mathematical model ?

Comment: @Runsva Do you have reasonable bounds for the variables?

Comment: The data exhibits a change of sign before the asymptote. Your model cannot account for that.

Comment: @jared I do have reasonable bounds for my variables, I just wish to know how to set those bounds for the `leastsq` function.

Comment: @Runsva look into `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` instead. I'm not sure it will work, but you can set bounds for the variables using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways around this. One hacky but successful method is to perturb any x-values at the asymptote and clip y-values to be some high but finite value. Also note that your first parameter is numerator and not a denominator, and you probably need an `abs` before your exponent.

```py
from typing import Sequence

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def optimal_fx(x: np.ndarray, num: float, pow: float, shift: float) -> np.ndarray:
    i_close = x.searchsorted(shift)
    if abs(x[i_close] - shift) < 1e-2:
        x = x.copy()
        x[i_close] -= 1e-2  # perturb away from asymptote
    return (
        -num/np.abs(x - shift)**pow
    ).clip(min=-100)


def plot(
    data_x: np.ndarray, data_y: np.ndarray, pguess: Sequence[float], pfinal: Sequence[float],
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax: plt.Axes

    hires_x = np.linspace(start=data_x.min(), stop=data_x.max(), num=500)
    num, pow, shift = pfinal

    ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, label="Original Data")
    ax.plot(hires_x, optimal_fx(hires_x, *pguess), label="Guess")
    ax.plot(hires_x, optimal_fx(hires_x, *pfinal), label="Fit")
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=-50, top=10)
    ax.set_title(f'y = -{num:.2f}/(x - {shift:.2f})^{pow:.2f}')
    ax.legend()

    return fig


def main():
    x = np.array([
        0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10,
        10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17])
    y = np.array([
        0.00000000e+00, 2.47076895e-03, 9.66638150e-03, 1.97670203e-02, 3.42218835e-02,
        4.97943540e-02, 6.54004261e-02, 7.93484613e-02, 8.61083796e-02, 8.49273950e-02,
        6.70327841e-02, 3.45946900e-02, -2.24559129e-02, -1.17023372e-01, -2.49244700e-01,
        -4.27837601e-01, -6.61529080e-01, -9.62240010e-01, -1.35215046e+00, -1.84177480e+00,
        -2.46428273e+00, -3.25198094e+00, -4.24238794e+00, -5.53021367e+00, -7.23278230e+00,
        -9.57603920e+00, -1.31432215e+01, -1.99465466e+01, -1.45862198e+01, -1.01563667e+01,
        -7.19977087e+00, -5.03349403e+00, -3.37202972e+00, -2.07966002e+00])

    pguess = (10, 1.2, 13.5)
    pfinal, *_ = curve_fit(
        f=optimal_fx,
        xdata=x,
        ydata=y,
        p0=pguess,
        bounds=(
            (0.01, 0.1,  5),
            ( 100,  10, 15),
        ),
    )

    plot(x, y, pguess, pfinal)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: fit]

A better fit can be achieved by adding a linear term:

```py
from typing import Sequence

import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def optimal_fx(x: np.ndarray, num: float, pow: float, shift: float, a: float, b: float) -> np.ndarray:
    i_close = x.searchsorted(shift)
    if abs(x[i_close] - shift) < 1e-2:
        x = x.copy()
        x[i_close] -= 2e-2  # perturb away from asymptote
    return (
        -num/np.abs(x - shift)**pow + a*x + b
    ).clip(min=-100)


def plot(
    data_x: np.ndarray, data_y: np.ndarray, pguess: Sequence[float], pfinal: Sequence[float],
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax: plt.Axes

    hires_x = np.linspace(start=data_x.min(), stop=data_x.max(), num=500)
    num, pow, shift, a, b = pfinal

    ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, label="Original Data")
    ax.plot(hires_x, optimal_fx(hires_x, *pguess), label="Guess")
    ax.plot(hires_x, optimal_fx(hires_x, *pfinal), label="Fit")
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=-50, top=10)
    ax.set_title(f'y = -{num:.2f}/(x - {shift:.2f})^{pow:.2f} + {a:.2f}x + {b:.2f}')
    ax.legend()

    return fig


def main():
    x = np.array([
        0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10,
        10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17])
    y = np.array([
        0.00000000e+00, 2.47076895e-03, 9.66638150e-03, 1.97670203e-02, 3.42218835e-02,
        4.97943540e-02, 6.54004261e-02, 7.93484613e-02, 8.61083796e-02, 8.49273950e-02,
        6.70327841e-02, 3.45946900e-02, -2.24559129e-02, -1.17023372e-01, -2.49244700e-01,
        -4.27837601e-01, -6.61529080e-01, -9.62240010e-01, -1.35215046e+00, -1.84177480e+00,
        -2.46428273e+00, -3.25198094e+00, -4.24238794e+00, -5.53021367e+00, -7.23278230e+00,
        -9.57603920e+00, -1.31432215e+01, -1.99465466e+01, -1.45862198e+01, -1.01563667e+01,
        -7.19977087e+00, -5.03349403e+00, -3.37202972e+00, -2.07966002e+00])

    pguess = (10, 1, 14, 0, 0)
    pfinal, *_ = curve_fit(
        f=optimal_fx,
        xdata=x,
        ydata=y,
        p0=pguess,
        bounds=(
            (0.01, 0.1,  5, -100, -100),
            ( 100,  10, 15,  100,  100),
        ),
    )

    plot(x, y, pguess, pfinal)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: with linear]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! This is really neat, and is a functional workaround. This method works, albeit the fits aren't the most ideal. But I suppose that's due to the function I'm trying to fit, and not the method you showed.